# Cabinet LED strip question

Tags: led

I'm thinking of putting in a single color LED strip for under cabinet lighting and RGB LED strip for over cabinet lighting, both with dimmers. I plan to plug in a power supply above the microwave cabinet which has one plug free, can i connect both LED strips and dimmers onto a single power supply? Of course the paths of current will be separated (i.e first set of red and black wires going down for under cabinet and second set going up for the RGB strip from the power supply). Also, does the type of power supply matter?

I plan to use one of these dimmers for the single color LED strip
[https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51qedrgjUPL.*SY355*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51qedrgjUPL._SY355_.jpg)
OR
http://www.photo138.com/0/AWS/YC00400-1.JPG

And for the RGB strip, either a 24 or 44 key remote IR controller.

Answers are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's fine to share the DC power supply, as long as it has enough capacity for the lights at absolute max power.

- 5050's take 1.2 amps per 60 LEDs (typically 1 metre), 0.4A per channel.
- 3528's take 0.4 amps per 60 LEDs (typically 1 metre).